# Json file has special char but still wanted to Parse Json in to object in C#

Tags: json

I have following JSON but need to parse it into C# object. 
But I am getting message that JSON is not well formatted.

```
{
[
        "<a target="\&quot;WindowA1\&quot;" href="%5C%22http: //www.google.com/test%5C%22">1234568</a>",
        "<a target="\&quot;WindowA1\&quot;" href="%5C%22http: //www.google.com/test%5C%22">1234568</a>"
]
}
```

How to handle the " inside the " while parsing the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "JSON" is totally broken. You don't parse broken JSON. You go to the amateurs who tried to produce JSON and failed miserably doing it, and tell them off and make them fix it.

If that doesn't work then you tell your boss to make them fix it.

I'll repeat that: You never, ever parse broken JSON data.